# Main Image not updating when swatch is selected Magento 2.0.8

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, magento2.0.8

Having an issue on Magento 2.0.8 where I have a configurable product and simple products associated with it.

The simple product have images and on the configurable product there are swatches shown for each one of the simple products. But when you select one the main image does not change.

I have checked the settings and everything looks okay. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Associate product has valid image ??

Comment: Same symptoms.. not sure if same issue. Products were imported instead of created manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues and am unsure if this may be a bug **MAGETWO-57210** or **MAGETWO-70169** on github.

For me this went away by doing the following however, check  "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" and "Used in Product Listing" for the attribute are set to "yes".

There were other fixes suggested here however, the above is what fixed for me.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6195

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'Magic Zoom Plus' plugin (alot of magento shops do) then this causes a conflict when using the visual swatch option (via colour palette). Using product image as swatch or text swatch seems to be unaffected. Either disable the Magic Zoom completely or you can edit this file to add exclusions for specific skus:

app/code/MagicToolbox/MagicZoomPlus/Observer/FixLayoutAfter.php

After line 85, put:

```
        if ($product->getSku() == 'APPLE') {
            $isEnabled = false;
            $magiczoomplus->params->setValue('enable-effect', 'No', 'product');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need just to change this setting for your Product Attribute https://prnt.sc/ZEMHUBCKBgWk

In my case it helped.